# React Table: resetting filters programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm using React-Table 6.7.6, and want to reset all filters programatically.

Right now, I've got this code:

```
return (
    <div>
        <ReactTable
            className="-striped -highlight"
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            filterable={true}
            defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row, column) => {
                const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id;
                return row[id] !== undefined
                    ? String(row[id]).includes(filter.value)
                    : true;
            }}
        />
    </div>
);
```

Is there a way to reset the filter values without digging into the guts of this thing too much?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it.

1) When you initiate your parent component, make it stateful and give it a 'filtered' property with an empty array, like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        filtered: []
    };
}
```

2) When you set up your React Table component, connect its "filtered" property to state, like this:

```
filtered={this.state.filtered}
```

3) Connect filtering to state, like this:

```
onFilteredChange={filtered => {this.setState({ filtered });}}
```

4) Hook up a button or whatever you want to reset the filters, with an onClick method like this:

```
onClick={()=>this.setState({ filtered: [] })}>
```

Comment: Hi Boris, I`m getting problem with custom filtering with dropdown in react-table. Could you please share any link or example to create dynamically dropdown as per values in column and filter the data?

Comment: Hey, Ram. I'm not working at that company anymore and don't have access to this code. The way I would do it would be to:
1) Get an array of the unique values in the original data, something like this: uniqueArray =  [...(new Set(originalArray))];
2) Populate a select element from that array with a  .forEach( return OptionHere) type deal (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)
3) Follow the steps in my original answer to hook the select element's value into the table filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm in react-table v6.11.4.

The only change I made was to use React Hooks like this:

```
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);

const handleFilteredChanged = (filterList) => {
  setFiltered(filterList);
};

const handleResetFilters = () => {
  setFiltered([]);
};

<ReactTable
    filtered={filtered}
    filterable
    onFilteredChange={handleFilteredChanged}
    ...
```

Thank you [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3019008/boris-k) for posting the answer.